# django - authenthicate - missing required potential argument 'self'

Tags: python, django

I have a custom auth backend and I am trying to connect users with it.

This is the backend

```
import logging
from .models import Users

class OwnAuthBackend(object):

    def authenticate(self, email, password):
        try:
            user = Users.objects.get(email=email)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
            else:
                return None
        except Users.DoesNotExist:
            logging.getLogger("error_logger").error("user with login %s does not exists " % login)
            return None
        except Exception as e:
            logging.getLogger("error_logger").error(repr(e))
            return None


    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            user = Users.objects.get(sys_id=user_id)
            if user.is_active:
                return user
            return None
        except Users.DoesNotExist:
            logging.getLogger("error_logger").error("user with %(user_id)d not found")
            return None
```

And this is in the `view.py`

```
email = form.cleaned_data['email_field']
                password = form.cleaned_data['password']
                user = OwnAuthBackend.authenticate(email=email, password=password)

                if user is not None:
                    messages.success(request, 'You logged in successfully!')
                    return redirect('index')
                else:
                    messages.warning(request, 'Credentials were wrong. Failed to log in!')
                    return redirect('index')

                message.error(request, 'Something went wrong while logging you in..')
                return redirect('index')
```

The import:

```
from main.backends import OwnAuthBackend
```

Error is in the title
I really have no idea what `self` I have to make, tried placing the `request` there but that didn't work.

According to: `users.is_authenticated` - custom user model, the user is logged in if I use `user = OwnAuthBackend.authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)`

But the problem is, if I go to control panel, the user isn't logged in anymore, the session doesn't keep, probably because ACP uses `user.` instead of `users.`

Comment: You should not be calling your backend directly at all. Call Django's own authenticate method, then login. This is all well explained in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to access the function with the object created by your class.

```
temp = OwnAuthBackend()
user = temp.authenticate(email=email, password=password)
```

Comment: And user doesn't get logged in, probably due to my custom user model... There is no error this time tho'

Comment: well in your class you need to call the authenticate function of django and then pass the authenticated to the login function of django, and return it in your view, hope thats what you are looking for @maxNomarkl